# MySQL: Disallow foreign key to a particular field

Tags: mysql, database-design, foreign-keys, mysql-workbench, database-administration

We have multiple developers who manage the database changes for their respective modules for a project which is still a work in progress.

I want to ensure that nobody references a particular field of one of the tables as a Foreign Key in another table; because in future, I want to be able to change the value of that field, without having to worry about the dependencies.

How can I prevent / disallow / block foreign key relationships on a particular field?

Comment: The best way to solve this is to establish a code review policy for schema changes. You can tell them "hey, don't reference this column, because it's still under development," and decline their schema change.

Comment: The documentation suggests that `REFERENCES` may be used as a column-level privilege, but I tried it out and I can't get it to work. In my test, I can grant table-level `REFERENCES` privilege to a user, but I can't grant the privilege only for certain columns.